# How to get a linefeed when writing files with ActionScript with Adobe Indesign Scripting

Tags: actionscript, adobe-indesign

I'm writing some scripts in ActionScript to automate some tasks in Adobe Indesign 2019 (part of the Creative Cloud Suite), but this applies to all scripting for all applications in Adobe Creative Cloud.

I don't want to use *ExtendScript Toolkit* for editing/running the script, because it is terribly slow.

Because there is no such thing as `console.log()` available (at least that I'm aware of) and `alert()` will stop for user input to continue, I created a small file logger, but it does not append the file, but keeps on overwriting the first line. I use `tail -f indesign.log` to monitor the log file.

Here is the code of the logger

```js
function logger(message){
  var logFilePath =  new File ('indesign.log');
  logFilePath.encoding = 'UTF-8';
  try {
    logFilePath.open('a');
       }
  catch(err) {
              logFilePath.close();
              logFilePath.open('a');
             }
    logFilePath.write(new Date().toLocaleString() +": "  +   message + "\n");
    //logFilePath.writeln(new Date().toLocaleString() +": "  +   message + "\n");
    logFilePath.close()
        }

logger("Script started")
logger("2nd line")
logger("3rd line")
logger("4th line")
logger("Script finished")
```

I tried also using `writeln` instead of `write`, but it does not make a difference.

I tried different line feeds, like `"\n"` and `"\r\n"`, but it does not make a difference.

I tried different `File.open` options like `.open('w')`, `.open('ra')`. The documentation about this is either not clear or really outdated (Or I just can't find it).

Any suggestions in the comments about the best IDE to edit/run ActionScripts is highly appreciated.

Comment: This works absolutely fine for me. Ran it through ESTK and from InDesign script panel. It adds a new line every time you run it. Tested with CS5.5

Comment: @NicolaiKant If you log some more lines, will it append to the file? The first line is always overwritten when I execute the code.

Comment: Wednesday, February 06 2019 23:55:27: Script started
Wednesday, February 06 2019 23:55:27: 2nd line
Wednesday, February 06 2019 23:55:27: 3rd line
Wednesday, February 06 2019 23:55:27: 4th line
Wednesday, February 06 2019 23:55:27: Script finished

Comment: The output I am getting. The comment removes the CRs

Comment: I run a copy of your script, did not change anything apart from pointing the file path for the log file to the desktop

Comment: When I open the file in a texteditor (Atom), it’s all on one line.  I’m on macOs btw.

Comment: So did I. Atom, Mac OSX. I do have lines separated for every entry

Comment: You can try to add line explicitly logger("Script started\n"), although on mine I will get double new line